# Backend module: Link to another backend module in TYPO3 9

Tags: typo3, backend

Let's say I have to different extensions with two different backend modules. Registered like:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
            'Vendor.ext',
            'ext',
            'controller1',
            '',
            [
                'Controller1' => 'any1',
            ],
            [
                'access' => 'user,group',
                'icon' => '...',
                'labels' => '...',
            ]
        );
```

And in the second extension also like:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
        'Vendor.ext2',
        'ext2',
        'controller2',
        '',
        [
            'Controller2' => 'any2',
        ],
        [
            'access' => 'user,group',
            'icon' => '...',
            'labels' => '...',
        ]
    );
```

How can I build a link from ext1 in the module to ext2?

What did I tried before in FLUID was:

```
<f:link.action action="any2" controller="Controller2" extensionName="ext">click me</f:link.action>
or
<f:be.link route="/ext/Ext2Controller2/">click me</f:be.link> (by copying the route that's available via GET parameter)
```

No luck yet - any ideas? Or how to get the correct route if be.link would be the correct function?

Comment: If I would use an own ViewHelper, same failure as I would use f:be.link

Example: 
$uriBuilder = ObjectUtility::getObjectManager()->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Routing\UriBuilder::class);
return $uriBuilder->buildUriFromRoute('/ext/Ext2Controller2/')->getPath();
Error message: "Unable to generate a URL for the named route /ext/Ext2Controller2/ because this route was not found."
Same question: How to get the correct route?

Comment: Even stranger: I searched in the backend module configuration in the part Backendroutes. There is a route defined. And if I copy and paste it into my ViewHelper the same error still comes up "Unable to generate a URL for the named route /ext/Ext2Controller2/ because this route was not found."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Finally I found the reason. 
It's simply possible to use the existing viewhelper like `<f:be.link route="lux_LuxLeads">click me</f:be.link>`
But the route must be the key and not the path. The key can be picked in the backend module `configuration` and `backendroutes`